# Infinite loop when dispatching in componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch, react-redux

I'm working in a React + Redux + redux-thunk codebase and I'm seeing some odd behavior. If I attempt to execute *TWO* actions in componentWillMount, the second action will infinitely loop.

Here's the `componentWillMount`:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { actions } = this.props;

  // Action #1 (synchronous)
  actions.openLoader();

  // Action #2 (promise-based fetch)
  actions.getListingsPurchased().then(() => {
    actions.closeLoader();
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

The first action, `openLoader()` is a simple state update. The second action does a fetch to the server. Action file here:

```
export function openLoader() {
  return {
    type: TYPES.SET_LOADER_OPEN
  };
}

export function getListingsPurchased() {
  return dispatch => {
    return fetch'URL GOES HERE', { 'credentials': 'include' })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(response => {
        return dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LISTINGS, data: response.data });
      });
  };
}
```

If I was to *remove* the first action `openLoader()` from `componentWillMount` the infinite loop does not happen. Otherwise the `fetch` call will keep repeating endlessly.

Any help would be appreciated, I seem to have hit a wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the best place for breaking infinite loop is in Redux reducer. Reducer is the place where you have to decide if you going to update the state of your app -> will trigger re-render of your components -> will trigger fetch action.

So try to put in place some reducer condition where you can recognize that state was already fetched before and you not going to update the state.